# lost apps after backup and restore on Samsung Kies

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung-kies, restore

I downloaded Kies because there is a software issue on the phone.  So I backed up the phone to Kies on my laptop then did a factory reset on the phone.  Then I restored the phone from the laptop but seem to have lost all the apps.  Help!

Answer (score -1):

I say go to play store, when you will open my apps section the backed up apps will be downloaded automatically. Make sure that you are connected to WiFi or 3G .

Comment: Indeed, this will get the apps back - however, it will *not* restore app data.

Comment: that's what taking Backup with Kies does it copies all data on Internal srorage i.e. app data

Comment: @coolhz that's what I thought, but after restore I lost a lot of my data. I don't see any of my tasks in Tasker anymore. WHy could this be?